# getting the name of a builtin class w/o using regex

Tags: python

Is there an easy way that I can extract the name of a built in class from its string representation? For instance getting 'int' from the `int` class? Calling `str(int)` returns `"<class 'int'>"` which is more than I need. I am trying not to use regular expressions to remove the extra characters.

Comment: whats the reason not to use int.__name__?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> int.__name__
'int'
```

In fact, this works with any class, not just builtin classes:

```
>>> class test:
...     pass
...
>>> test.__name__
'test'
```